# Import android project into Android Studio and export a signed APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, I have this old project (from when I started learning Java first time) that I'd like to import into Android Studio. When I import a project library no errors pop up. But nothing shows afterwards. Just "Nothing to show". And when I try to "Make project" nothing happens.

Note that I'm a newbie and slowly improves when I can.

Comment: Visit this link for complete details http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#migrate

Comment: It seems to be importing fine.. I just need to open the project after I've imported it..